# Using machine learning to compare the probability of success of two different treatment strategies

Tags: machine-learning, probability

I would like to preface by saying I am relatively new in the world of machine learning, however I have a decent background in statistics.

I have a large database of patients who underwent a certain procedure. This database contains patient information, as well as the outcome of the procedure (success or failure). There are two different treatment strategies used for this type of procedure, let's call them A and B.

What I want to do is create "calculator" that will take user input on the various patient characteristics and then output the strategy that has the highest chance of success for this particular patient.

For example, let's say we have 3 patient characteristics (there are more in the actual database): age, gender, and BMI.
User input:
Age = 58
Gender = Male
BMI = 28
Output: Strategy A has a better chance of success

I came up with a potential way to do this, by creating two models (eg logistic regression), one for each strategy, and training them and testing them using my database. Then I will get user input for the patient characteristics and use those in each model to get the probability of success for each strategy (using model.predict_proba in python). Lastly, I will compare the two probabilities and suggest the strategy with the highest value.

I am not sure if this is a correct way of approaching this problem, or if there is a better method.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: I don't think you need two models. You can simply fit a single model to your data and then for the new data have two versions that are only different with respect to the strategy. Then predict the probability of success for both of them and choose the one with higher probability of success.

Comment: It's a particular version of causal inference on observational data, where you don't want to just compare the treatments, but even figure out whether there are subsets of patients with differential efficacy (which [even for a randomized trials you'd need a much larger sample size than for just the treatment main effect](https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2018/03/15/need-16-times-sample-size-estimate-interaction-estimate-main-effect/)).

Comment: Your two LRs are equivalent to a single one with every model term having an interaction with treatment (assuming you penalize the same way), still needs making sure to adjust for confounders the right way or propensity score strategy or the like on top.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments AminShn and @Björn. So, if I am getting this correctly, you suggest creating a single model that accounts for the interaction of each variable with the treatment strategy and then running it twice for new data (once for each strategy), and comparing the probability of success with each strategy?

Comment: Since in your title you're saying Machine Learning I assume using something like Random Forest, Neural Nets, and etc that automatically take care of the interactions among variables. So yes, I would train an ML algorithm with the strategy as a binary input among other inputs. After training the model, for predicting for a new situation, I keep all inputs fixed except for strategy predicting two probabilities for each strategy and then deciding based on the results of their outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Following my comments, I have made an example to show my suggested approach. First I simulate some data with a binary outcome, and two continues predictors and a binary variable for strategy:

```
# Some R code to simulate data

library(boot) # Package contains the logit transform

T <- 1000
set.seed(123)
x_1 <- runif(T, 0, 10)
x_2 <- runif(T, 0, 10)
strategy <- c(rep(1,T/2), rep(0,T/2))
alpha <- 1
beta_1 <- 0.2
beta_2 <- -0.5
beta_3 <- 0.4
logit_p <-  alpha + beta_1 * x_1 + beta_2 * x_2 + beta_3 * strategy 
p <- inv.logit(logit_p)
y <- rbinom(T, 1, p)

df = data.frame(y = as.factor(y), x1 = x_1, x2 = x_2, x3 = strategy)
```

Then I fit a random forest model to the data:

```
# -- fitting random forest
library(randomForest)
library(dplyr)

rf.fit = randomForest(y ~ ., data = df[1:T-1,]) # I keep the last row out as future observation
```

For brevity I skipped the cross-validation and hyperparameter tuning steps here. Now we use the fitted model to predict the probability of the outcome for both scenarios (using strategy 1 and 2):

```
strategy_1 = df[T,]
strategy_2 = strategy_1 %>% mutate(x3 = 1) # switching the strategy of the query from 0 to 1


prob_1 = predict(rf.fit, newdata = strategy_1 ,type="prob")
prob_2 = predict(rf.fit, newdata = strategy_2 ,type="prob")

# --- Printing probability of success for each strategy
print(prob_1[2])
print(prob_2[2])

> print(prob_1[2])
[1] 0.192
> print(prob_2[2])
[1] 0.222
```

As we expected (according to the beta_3 coefficient), strategy 2 is more favourable showing higher probability of success.

Answer (score 0):

What you're referring to is estimating an optimal treatment rule. Assuming you can satisfy certain causal assumptions, one approach for this is using a counterfactual framework. Denote the set of all possible treatment rules as $\mathcal{D}$ , the rule $d$ that maximizes the counterfactual $E[Y_d]$ is the optimal rule.

$$
d_{\text{opt}} \equiv \text{arg max}_{d \in \mathcal{D}} E [Y_{d}]
$$

A strategy to do this is to learn the conditional average treatment effect (CATE); this is frequently referred to as the blip function in this scenario: $E[Y_1 - Y_0 | V]$ where $V$ is the set of variables you want to use to define your rule. If you want to maximize $E[Y_d]$, then you would assign individuals to the treatment group where the blip function is positive, and to the control where the blip function is negative.

A valid way to do all this, and incorporate machine learning is to:

- Estimate the efficient influence function of the average treatment effect using a machine learning approach of your choice.
- Regress this on the set of variables $V$ using a machine learning algorithm of your choice.
- Generate predictions from this model as your estimate of the CATE
- Assign treatment according to the sign of the CATE for each individual

For an example of all this used in a real study, see this paper (https://academic.oup.com/aje/advance-article/doi/10.1093/aje/kwac217/6957041).

Applying this to your example:

```
{r}
T <- 1000
set.seed(123)
x_1 <- runif(T, 0, 10)
x_2 <- runif(T, 0, 10)
strategy <- c(rep(1,T/2), rep(0,T/2))
alpha <- 1
beta_1 <- 0.2
beta_2 <- -0.5
beta_3 <- 0.4
logit_p <-  alpha + beta_1 * x_1 + beta_2 * x_2 + beta_3 * strategy 
p <- boot::inv.logit(logit_p)
y <- rbinom(T, 1, p)

df = data.frame(y = as.factor(y), x1 = x_1, x2 = x_2, x3 = strategy)
```

Estimate the efficient influence function of the average treatment effect using a machine learning approach. In this case using a Super Learner with a GLM and random forest.

```
library(dplyr)
library(SuperLearner)

learners = c("SL.glm", "SL.randomForest")

propensity.fit <- SuperLearner(df$x3, df[, c("x1", "x2")], family = "binomial", SL.library = learners)

propensity <- predict(propensity.fit, onlySL = TRUE)$pred[, 1]

y.fit = SuperLearner(df$y, df[, c("x1", "x2", "x3")], family = "binomial", SL.library = learners)

ya <- predict(y.fit, onlySL = TRUE)$pred[, 1]
y1 <- predict(y.fit, mutate(df, x3 = 1), onlySL = TRUE)$pred[, 1]
y0 <- predict(y.fit, mutate(df, x3 = 0), onlySL = TRUE)$pred[, 1]

eif_ate <- ((2*df$x3 - 1) / propensity) * (df$y - ya) + y1 - y0
```

Estimate the blip function by regressing the EIF of the ATE on $V$ and then predicting

```
blip.fit <- SuperLearner(eif_ate, df[, c("x1", "x2")], SL.library = learners)
blip <- predict(blip.fit, onlySL = TRUE)$pred[, 1]
```

Assign treatment according to the sign of the blip for each individual. In this scenario, there is no treatment effect heterogeneity, so everyone should be assigned treatment.

```
d <- ifelse(blip > 0, 1, 0)
# or if you want to minimize Y
# ifelse(blip < 0, 1, 0)
table(d)
```